# Extensions of representations

Tags: representation-theory

I'm again confronted with an exercise from Etingof's book "Introduction to representation theory" (page 30 of http://math.mit.edu/~etingof/replect.pdf)

**Problem 2.22.**

1. Let $A=\mathbb{C}[x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}]$ and $V_{a},V_{b}$ be 1-dimensional representations in which the elements $x_{i}$ act by $a_{i},b_{i}\in\mathbb{C}$ respectively. Find $\operatorname{Ext}^{1}(V_{a},V_{b})$ and classify all 2-dimensional representations of $A$.
2. Let $B$ be the algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ generated by elements $x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}$ with the defining relations $$x_{i}x_{j}=0 \ \forall \ 1\leq i,j\leq n$$Show that for $n>1$ the algebra $B$ has infinitely many non-isomorphic indecomposable representations.

This time I am really at point blank... Could someone give my a hint on how to start with this problem? Many thanks in advance

Comment: There are no nontrivial extensions unless the $a_{i}$ and $b_{i}$ are the same for all $i$. To do this, consider decomposing a $2$-dimensional representation into common generalized eigenspaces for the $x_{i}$. If $a_{i}$ and $b_{i}$ are the same, then you have non-trivial extension classes. You can choose a basis such that each $x_{i}$ is upper triangular. Now think about putting things in Jordan normal form. To do the classification part, note that any two dimensional representation is an extension of two one dimensional representation, as every irreducible is one dimensional.

Comment: For the second problem, try showing that there exist indecomposibles of dimension $m$ for each natural number $m$. This can be done either by constructing a chain of nontrivial extensions of the unique one-dimensional irreducible with itself, or by constructing them by hand (by choosing $n$, $m \times m$ matrices that satisfy the defining relations).

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Comment: Ok. I'll make the comment into an answer soon.

Comment: For the second problem, is there any non-zero 1-dim irreducible representation? It seems $x_i$ acts by 0 for all $i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Problem 1, let me prove a more general fact.

Let $k$ be a field. Suppose $A$ is an associative, but not necessarily commutative, $k$-algebra and let $Z$ be its center. Let $V_{1}$, $V_{2}$ be simple left $A$-modules (finite dimensional or countable dimensional if the algebra is over $\mathbb{C}$) over $A$. Then, $Z$ acts via scalars on $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$ by Schur's Lemma. Suppose there exists some $z \in Z$ such that $z$ acts via different scalars $z_{1}, z_{2}$ on $V_{1}, V_{2}$. Then, there are no nontrivial extensions between $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$.

To see this, suppose $V$ is an extension of $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$ such that $V_{1} \subseteq V $ and $V_{2}$ a quotient of $V$. Then, $z$ has distinct generalized eigenvalues on $V$ and is hence diagonalizable. This tells us that $V = V_{1} \oplus V_{2}$ is an eigenspace decomposition of $V$ with respect to distinct eigenvalues of $z$. But the $z_{i}$-eigenspace of $z$ is actually a submodule of $V$ because for any $a \in A$, $v \in V_{i}$,

$$z(a \cdot v) = a(z \cdot v) = z_{i} a\cdot v.$$

Hence, the decomposition of $V$ into $V_{1} \oplus V_{2}$ is a decomposition of $A$-modules. Hence, the extension is trivial.